# recyclerView.setAdapter does not accept ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to populate RecyclerView with simple String data but `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` gives error. What's the problem?

I am new to recyclerview.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
String []data = {"ankush", "kapoor"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: ArrayAdapter is an adapter for a `ListView`. For a `RecyclerView` you have to use a `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: "gives error" - Yes, it should say that the parameter type is not correct, and it should tell you what is expected. What resource are you using to learn RecyclerView?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to create a custom Adapter class for a RecyclerView. Here is the example of RecyclerView custom adapter class :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;
<your string array list>

public CustomAdapter(Context context,<your string arraylist>) {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.<your string arraylist>=<your string arraylist>;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.serial_number.setText(<your string array[position]>);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return <size of your string array list>;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView serial_number;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        serial_number = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.serialNo_CL);
        }
    }
}
```