# set a default adapter with a unique string

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

i past all my time creating custom adapters, that i forgot about how to create a simple adapter that treats a unique string.

So basicly i want a adapter that shows a list of strings  so i created a recycle view, a ArrayAdapter and tried to set the arrayAdapter in the recvlew view.

**Like this:**

```
   tA = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.teamA);

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, teamA);

            tA.setAdapter(adapter);

        RecyclerView tA;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        ArrayList<String> teamA = new ArrayList<>();

                teamA.add(participant);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Recyclerview you need to create custom adapter. ArrayAdapter is not accept by recyclerview

Refer this - [recyclerView.setAdapter does not accept ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926071/recyclerview-setadapter-does-not-accept-arrayadapter)