# I want to list the information I got from json in my project in the recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I want to list the information I got from json in my project in the recyclerview, but I could not succeed. Can you help me?

My Codes :

```
RecyclerView countries = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.countries);
        countries.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        CityList cityList = new CityList();
        try {
            BufferedReader jsonReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jsondata)));
            StringBuilder jsonBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String line = null; (line = jsonReader.readLine()) != null; ) {
                jsonBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            cityList = gson.fromJson(jsonBuilder.toString(), CityList.class);
        }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            Log.e("jsonFile", "file not found.");
         }
        catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("jsonFile","ioerror");
        }


        List <String> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0; i<cityList.getList().size(); i++){
            data.add(cityList.getList().get(i).getName());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.country_item_layout, data);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.country_item_layout);
        countries.setAdapter(adapter);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/countries"
tools:listitem="@layout/country_item_layout"
app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
/>
 </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

COUNTRİES XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 app:cardElevation="3dp"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
 >
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:name="com.example.ExampleFragment" >
 <RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginVertical="7dp"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="15dp">
    
    
<TextView
 android:id="@+id/countryName"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
 android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
 android:textColor="@color/black"
 android:text="Türkiye"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:textSize="15dp" ></TextView>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Temperature"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="15dp" ></TextView>
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

PROBLEMS:
'setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter)' in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView' cannot be applied to '(android.widget.ArrayAdapter<java.lang.String>)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayAdapter is not gonna work with RecyclerView. You have to create your own custom adapter. Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) and build your own custom adapter.

Answer (score 1):

ArrayAdapter is not applicable for RecyclerView. You need to implement your own Adapter. See this answer for possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38931340/7703505